# Devkitpro msys errors

Tags: nintendo

Whenever I try to install devkitPro, I get these command prompt windows for short periods of time with the following errors:

```
error: msys: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" is unknown
error: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" could not be looked up remotely
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 msys                                           206.2 KiB   729K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 msys.sig                                       438.0   B   214K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
error: msys: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" is unknown
error: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" could not be looked up remotely
error: failed to update msys (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
 dkp-libs is up to date
 dkp-windows is up to date
error: failed to synchronize all databases
```

```
error: msys: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" is unknown
error: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" could not be looked up remotely
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

```
error: msys: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" is unknown
error: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" could not be looked up remotely
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

```
error: msys: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" is unknown
error: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" could not be looked up remotely
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

Interestingly enough, when I go to the C:/devkitPro folder, I find that I have no devkitpro related files in there whatsoever - just an msys2 folder. I did manage to find a repository online with the files that would have been installed... but when I try to build a project, it says that it can't find the appropriate .specs file.

I would like to know if there is any way I can properly install devkitPro on my windows 10 device. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The msys2 issue could be solved by [updating your key stores](https://www.msys2.org/news/#2020-06-29-new-packagers):

```
curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
pacman-key --verify msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig
```

Then, re-run `pacman -Syu`. By default, msys2 will not install devkitPro to `C:\devkitpro`, but to somewhere like `/opt/devkitpro` within msys2.

Comment: The solution kind of works... It took some fiddling around, but I got to the point where I could install with no errors, as well as make a project with no errors. However, I get no sign of the final build of an example project. In other words, nothing will happen.